# SQL grouping by one column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, distinct

I'm trying to combine columns from two tables, and have it only display only unique name (Full Name) on each row while removing duplicate names. I have used SELECT DISTINCT which works to an extent, but it shows unique names for each (File ID). This still leaves me with duplicates as a whole.

I originally preferred to use GROUP BY, but it give an error "each group by expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference." I don't know what this means.

Sorry, if this is simple but I'm just starting out learning SQL!

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3000
    p.FileDateID as "File ID", 
    p.CategoryID as "Category ID", 
    fd.OrganizationID as "Organization"
    concat(p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, P.LastName) as "Full Name"
    p.FirstName as "First Name", 
    p.MiddleName as "Middle Name", 
    p.LastName as "Last Name",
    p.Title, 
    p.Street, 
    p.City, 
    p.State, 
    p.Zip, 
    p.WorkPhone as "Work Phone", 
    p.MobilePhone as "Mobile Phone", 
    p.EMail

FROM 
    byte.dbo.Party p

INNER JOIN
    byte.dbo.FileData fd ON fd.FileDataID = p.FileDataID

#   GROUP BY
#   5

ORDER BY
    4 ASC

;
```

Comment: you can group by multiple fields `GROUP BY (field1, field2)`. You also have a capital P in your select `P.LastName`.

Comment: Use the GroupBy clause again and make sure the columns you use in the GroupBy clause have table name or alias appended before the column name. Ambiguous columns in the group by clause is the source of "each group by expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference." error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we'll get unique names and the min(value) of the rest of the columns in the resulting table. 
If there's more than 1 value in any of the other columns for a given Full Name, we'll see the lowest value returned in the column. 
If there's only 1 value in one of the other columns for a given Full Name, then the min() is trivial and we'll see that one value returned for that column

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3000
   min(p.FileDateID) as "File ID", 
   min(p.CategoryID) as "Category ID", 
   min(fd.OrganizationID) as "Organization"
   concat(p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName) as "Full Name"
   min(p.FirstName) as "First Name", 
   min(p.MiddleName) as "Middle Name", 
   min(p.LastName) as "Last Name",
   min(p.Title) as Title,    
   min(p.Street) as Street, 
   min(p.City) as City, 
   min(p.State) as State, 
   min(p.Zip) as Zip, 
   min(p.WorkPhone) as "Work Phone", 
   min(p.MobilePhone) as "Mobile Phone", 
   min(p.EMail) as Email
FROM 
   byte.dbo.Party p
INNER JOIN
   byte.dbo.FileData fd ON fd.FileDataID = p.FileDataID
GROUP BY
   concat(p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName)
ORDER BY 4 ASC
;
```

Comment: This worked exactly how I needed it to, thanks a lot! I've been trying to find a solution all day.

Answer (score 1):

> I originally preferred to use GROUP BY, but it give an error "each group by expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference." I don't know what this means.

That error actually explains exactly what your problem is, and why your approach is flawed. It's trying to tell you that you can only select fields you group by, everything else has to be either dropped or aggregated.

And that's exactly what needs to happen, because you complain that if you go around the grouping mechanism and try to "outsmart" it you get duplicated rows because the file IDs are different -- of course they're different and that makes the entire row a new row. Grouping would have prevented selecting that field altogether.

So what you need to do is figure out exactly what data you want out of the database, because if you really do want the IDs, then you'll get every row. If you just want the distinct names, word your query appropriately and use `group by`.

And one last note, this:

```
ORDER BY
    4 ASC
```

Now you're just being silly.